# how to display customly added attribute columns value in the frontend of magento

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I recently added a 'tooltip description' column to an attribute. I used this following code

```
$fieldset->addField('tooltip', 'text', array(
    'name' => 'tooltip',
    'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Tooltip'),
    'title' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Tooltip')
));
```

to add a field in my `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\Main.php`. This adds the extra field to the attribute-edit screen. I also added a column with type TEXT in the `eav_attribute` table  to make sure the property gets saved when editing your attribute. And it worked perfectly in the backend. See the following Image:

[image: tooltip attribute]

Now I want to show the **Tooltip Description** value in frontend where the attributes value are shown....say in attributes.phtml page. So what is the code to dispaly it in frontend.

Comment: What is the field name?

Comment: the field name is `tooltip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
<?php 
foreach ($this->getAttributes() as $_attribute){ 
    echo $_attribute->getTooltip();
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**

```
$attribute_code = $_data['code']; 
$attribute_details = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute_code); 
$attribute = $attribute_details->getData(); // returns array 


echo "<pre>";
print_r($attribute);
```

Comment: its not working....shouldn't the `getTooltip()` function needs an implementation !!!

Comment: I want to dispaly it in somewhere in the code :
`<tbody><?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
<tr>
<th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td></tr><?php endforeach; ?></tbody>`

Comment: yes you can get your value for "tooltip" as $attribute['tooltip']

Comment: the field value is getting saved?

Comment: yes...Ok I'm using it like this : 

`<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?><tr><th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?>  <span class="tooltip" onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, '<?php echo $attribute['tooltip']; ?>')"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/info_icon.gif');?>" align="absmiddle" /></span></th><td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td></tr><?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: sorry I mistakenly placed 
`$attribute_code = $_data['code']; 
$attribute_details=Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute_code); 
$attribute = $attribute_details->getData();`
this part outside the loop....its working now thanks a lot.....